# micropython - creating new data type - type of attribute

Tags: python, cpython, micropython

I'm creating a new data type.

The Python-native type I'm creating is: `can_message` and it only has two members (for now) and I want them to behave like elements in a struct.

`msg_id` is an `int`
`msg_data` is a `list`

However, in the table for these two entries for type `can_message`, I do not know what these two `qstr`s should be mapped two:

> I'm pretty sure the mapping is wrong for both entries:
>   The current entries say that `msg_id` is an alias for the `int` type and
>   `msg_data` is an alias for the type `list`

```
STATIC const mp_rom_map_elem_t can_message_type_locals_dict_table[] =
{
        {MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_msg_id), MP_ROM_PTR(&mp_type_int)},
        {MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_msg_data), MP_ROM_PTR(&mp_type_list)},

};

STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_DICT(can_message_type_locals_dict, can_message_type_locals_dict_table);

const mp_obj_type_t can_message_type =
{
    {&mp_type_type},
    .name = MP_QSTR_message,
    .print = can_message_obj_print,
    .make_new = can_message_make_new,
    .locals_dict = (mp_obj_t)&can_message_type_locals_dict,
    .attr = can_message_attr
};
```

Python:

```
dir(can_message)
# list('msg_id', 'msg_data')
msg = can_message()
dir(msg) 
# list('msg_id', 'msg_data')
```

The way `dir()` works - yes I've traced through the C-code - in both cases, it uses the same `can_message_type_locals_dict_table`

I want the user to be able to able to do the following.

```
msg = can_message()
msg.msg_id = 55
msg.msg_data = [1, 54, 25, 3, 5,3, 2, 2]
```

I traced through the code and `mp_store_attr` is called which then calls a function that I'm supposed to write (and I did) that makes sure that you cannot add a new attribute i.e. `msg.asdfsaf = 99`.

**QUESTION**

In `can_message_type_locals_dict_table` to what do I map each `qstr` when the underlying object it represents is a data item that can be assigned?